# Zend Form DatePicker

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, datepicker

I have a public function in my zend form, called select, whereby it consisit of and element select to add addmultioptions , each addmultioption has a specific form, which appears after selection, some forms though consists of a datepickers, but Im having a problem selecting on those select fields with datepickers. Bare in mind I am using Jquery and have included the Zendx length in my application.ini, and also tried extending the ZendX_JQuery_Form class.

I have a number of forms with datepickers using the same methods for each but not sure whats going on with this one. Heres my code below.

Heres an exmple of my code below.

```
<?php

class Form_Excel extends ZendX_JQuery_Form //Tried Both methods normally use the one below
class Form_Excel extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
}


    public function excel()
    {
        $type = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('type');
        $type->setLabel('Select a Type:')
             ->addMultiOption('1', ' Report1')
             ->addMultiOption('2', ' Report2')
             ->addMultiOption('3', ' Report3')
             ->addMultiOption('4', ' Report4')
             ->addMultiOption('5', ' Export5')
             ->addMultiOption('6', ' Report6')
             ->addMultiOption('7', ' Report7')
             ->addmultiOption('8', ' Report8');

        $type->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box','style' => 'padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;margin-bottom: -35px;clear: both;'))
             ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-custom search-width span5'))));

        $this->addElement($type);
    }

    public function 1()
    {
        $hidden = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('hidden');
        $hidden->setValue('status');
        $this->addElement($hidden); 

        $status = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('status');
        $status->setLabel('Current Status: ')
                    ->addMultiOption('', '--Select One--')
                    ->addMultiOption(1, 'First')
                    ->addMultiOption(2, 'Second')
                    ->addMultiOption(3, 'Contacted')

               ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box','style' => 'padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;clear: both;'));

        $status->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-12 form-control'));

        $this->addElement($status);

        //Assessed Before / After
        $before = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('before');
        $before     ->setLabel('Date Before: ')
                    ->addFilter('StripTags');
        $before     ->setJQueryParams(array(
                     'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                     'changeMonth'=> true,
                     'changeYear'=> true
                     ))
                     ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-4 field-box the-font print-container','style' => 'padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;'));


        $before->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-4 form-control the-font text-field'));

        $this->addElement($before);         

        $after = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('after');
        $after  ->setLabel('Date After: ')
                    ->addFilter('StripTags');
        $after  ->setJQueryParams(array(
                     'defaultDate' => date('d-m-y'),
                     'changeMonth'=> true,
                     'changeYear'=> true
                     ))
                     ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-4 field-box the-font print-container','style' => 'padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;'));


        $after->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-4 form-control the-font text-field'));

        $this->addElement($after);  


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit ->setLabel('Submit')
                ->setAttrib('class', 'btn-flat primary')
                ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','style' => 'width: 88%; padding-left:0;clear: both;'));
        $this->addElement($submit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using:

```
$this->view->form = new Form_Excel();
```

That typically only executes the `init()` method of the Form.

To execute another method, we would still instantiate the class but then call a method.

eg.

```
$this->view->form->excel();
```

then in view:

```
<?= $this->form ?>
```

would return the `select` element.

Comment: What you saying is this $form = new Form_Excel(); $form->excel();, Which i have already in the controller and <?phpecho $this->form;?>, in my view the form appeaers but I can't select on the datepicker field, I can't select on the field and pick a date

Comment: Yes because you are not extending `ZendX_Jquery_Form` for the date picker this is required, furthermore if it is loaded by `ajax` it still won't work and you will need to use the `.datepicker()` jquery method: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: How come some of the forms I didn't implement ZendX_Jquery_Form, but they still worked? and I tried that but im trying it again just to check if I haven't missed anything

Comment: Not winning still not picking it up

Comment: When selecting inspect element, this what im getting <input type="text" name="before" id="before" value="" class="col-md-4 form-control the-font text-field">, instead of <input type="text" name="s_after" id="s_after" value="" class="col-md-4 form-control the-font text-field hasDatepicker">